# Python get variable name instead of value

Tags: python, django

I need to get the variable name instead of the variable value.

I have a situation like this:

```
Type1 = 1
Type2 = 2

fields = [Type1, Type2]
for field in fields:
   value = field.__name__ #or something like 
   print(value)
```

Expected result is

```
Type1 
Type2
```

Ty for helping

Comment: It looks like you should have used a dict instead of two variables that are only related by their names...

Comment: What result do you expect if both variables have the same value?

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though i don't think there is any way (or i don't know) but an easy way is to store them in a dict like this;

```
my_dict = {'Type1': 1, 'Type2': 2}
```

Then to get the variable name, you just need to loop over the `my_dict` and get all the keys and simply use them as you want.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key)
```

this will give an output like this;

```
Type1
Type2
```

Comment: Type1 and Type2 are passed from url in django...

Comment: I don't think that has any problem with the solution. When you get them, you can first update the my_dict and store them inside it and then apply my solution